# Using stream.beginwrite to achieve fire-and-forget REST call?

Tags: c#, rest, asynchronous

I am attempting to call a RESTful service but I do not really want to even wait for the response (200/404/500).

I know this may sound trivial but, I have a unique scenario that, for some reason requires this. I have made my request like so:

```
        using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.BeginWrite(postData, 0, postData.Length, null, null);
        }
```

This appears to work but just feels wrong. Is this frowned-upon behavior? If so, what would be a preferred method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If this is your requirement then go on there is nothing wrong with it :)

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro there are two things ***very*** wrong with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See MSDN:

> EndWrite must be called once for every call to BeginWrite. You can do this either by using the same code that called BeginWrite or in a callback passed to BeginWrite.

So *by itself*, no - this could cause a leak. Also, though, if you start an *async* write, and dispose the `stream` immediately, the write is almost certainly to a closed/disposed stream (it is exceptionally unlikely that the second thread has even got *involved* at that point, let alone completed the write). Perhaps start a `Task` or `ThreadPool` item that does a regular `Write`?

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {
    using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream()) {
        stream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I had considered this approach but avoided it because it involved introducing additional code (and threading at that) too some old legacy 1.1 code. However, you make an excellent argument and I think it justifies the risk.